# How to pass one local URL to functions in another local URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, xampp, localhost

I'm calling content from one locally hosted site for use on another locally hosted site. (This is for the purposes of reproducing a cookieless URL from which I'll serve static content.)

I'm using the current version of XAMPP (5.6.12) with PHP version 5.6.12 and Apache 2.4.16 (Win32) on Windows 8.1.

The two sites (both found off of the \xampp\htdocs directory) are MAIN and STATIC, and are configured appropriately in the httpd-vhosts.conf file as well in the Windows hosts file. So, they each work, and each can retrieve content from the other (with the important exception explained below).

In STATIC there is a subdirectory named IMAGES containing MY.JPG; its local URL is therefore STATIC/IMAGES/MY.JPG when XAMPP is running, and it does display.

Within the files of my MAIN local domain, I can reference content on the STATIC local domain by prefixing the domain name with two forward-slashes, e.g., //STATIC/IMAGES/MY.JPG. And in fact, this code in my STATIC domain's INDEX.PHP will in fact retrieve and display the JPG:

```
<img style="display: inline;" src="//STATIC/IMAGES/MY.JPG" />
```

No problem there. But when I pass that path to getimagesize() or other PHP operators, like this:

```
$resource = "//STATIC/IMAGES/MY.JPG";
$getimagesize = getimagesize($resource);
```

...I get a message like this:

> Warning: getimagesize(//tmb-static/images/my.jpg): failed to open
>   stream: Permission denied in C:\xampp\htdocs\MAIN\INDEX.PHP on line 11

After reading about similar problems encountered by others, I checked to ensure that correct permissions are set for the folder I'm trying to open. To determine who the current user is when I execute this code locally, I ran:

```
$current_user = get_current_user();
print_r("current_user = " . $current_user . "\n");
```

...and it showed that the current user is SYSTEM.

I then did what has been suggested elsewhere, which is to give complete read, write, and all other accesses to SYSTEM for the STATIC folder and its subfolders, by following the appropriate steps for sharing folders and setting permissions. I did this not only for SYSTEM but also for Everyone, just in case.

Sadly, getimagesize() and similar operators throw the same "failed to open stream: Permission denied" message when I then ran the code, even though the image itself can be retrieved and displayed using simple HTML:

```
// This works and displays the retrieved image:
echo '<img style="display: inline;" src="//STATIC/IMAGES/MY.JPG" />';

// This immediately fails with message: "failed to open stream: Permission denied..."
$getimagesize = getimagesize('//STATIC/IMAGES/MY.JPG');
```

Provided that I've given full control to the STATIC folder and subfolders, as well as to the parent HTDOCS folder as well, what could be the cause and solution to this vexing problem?

**UPDATE**: By prefixing the STATIC URL with http:, like this:

```
http://STATIC/IMAGES/MY.JPG
```

...the error changes to

> failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden

But is this a red herring? Or is this just another layer of the problem, with the prefixing of HTTP: being the first step?

**UPDATE 2:**

By adding this to the .htaccess file for the STATIC domain:

```
AuthBasicAuthoritative On
AllowOverride All
```

...the error becomes:

```
getimagesize(http://STATIC/IMAGES/MY.JPG):failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
```

Notice this is after prefixing the domain URL with http:

Is there an authentication step I'm missing?

**UPDATE 3:**

It seems that while on localhost, I need to provide one type of URL for HTML image display and another for sending the image file to PHP functions. By removing:

```
AuthBasicAuthoritative On
AllowOverride All
```

...from the .htaccess file and then modifying my test code this way:

```
$html_url = "//STATIC/";
$php_url = "c:/xampp/htdocs/STATIC/";

echo '<img style="display: inline;" src="' . $html_url  . 'IMAGES/MY.JPG" />';
$getimagesize = getimagesize($php_url . 'IMAGES/MY.JPG');
print_r($getimagesize);
```

...the problem is solved. SURELY I don't have to maintain two different URLs for my local host (none of this is a problem on my live server) and edit my code accordingly???

Answer (score 0):

Please, don't change the file permissions! User System has already rights to read from any folder.

Your problem is in path logic. 
When browser reads HTML and sees path like '//STATIC/IMAGES/MY.JPG', it reads it as 'http://example.com/static/images/my.jpg', which means 'your_website_folder/static/images/my.jpg'.

When your server reads provided path, it sees 'some_root_folder/static/images/my.jpg'. That root folder is your system's root. Which in your case is probably 'C:/Windows/System32'. You can see the danger here, right?

So, as a solution a would advise creating a variable in php that will store your website's root folder:

```
define("__SITE_ROOT" , $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']); 
//this will define constant with /your_website_folder in it
```

Then you simply append the rest of your path, like so:

```
$img_path = __SITE_ROOT . $resource; // providing //static/images/my.jpg in a $resource
```

Comment: See the "update" I just added at the bottom of my post...I'm unclear if your solution works provided what I've discovered (i.e. that prefixing the local URL with http: seems to solve one problem, but then another surfaces).

Comment: No, your solution will store c:\xampp\htdocs\MAIN in __SITE_ROOT. I'm referencing resources in c:\xampp\htdocs\STATIC, so setting up a variable as you suggest just records the domain from which I'm sending requests, not the one where I wish to retrieve resources.

Comment: You can simply add /../ between __SITE_ROOT and $resource (your image path), like so: $img_path = __SITE_ROOT . "/../" . $resource;. this will return one folder back, and then read from your folder 'STATIC'.
There could be a more elegant solution, though.

Comment: See new info in Update 2, above.

Comment: "500 Internal Server Error" means there was an error in apache, most likely due to a bad server configuration - probably your edit in .htaccess. You could paste your .htaccess file.
Also, I really don't understand what you are trying to do: getimagesize(http ://STATIC/IMAGES/MY.JPG) -> getImageSize expects file path, not URL. So, follow what I wrote because this is heading in the wrong direction.

Comment: I tried your method, and it worked for passing the URL of the image to getimagesize() but not for displaying the image within the HTML. See Update 3 above.

Comment: What? http ://STATIC/? Did you set up that in hosts file or you expect for that to work just like that?
If latter - it will not! Xampp sets http ://127.0.0.1/ by default, and depends on your xampp config which is the root folder. If C:\xampp\htdocs\ is your root folder, then your image file can be shown on this URL http ://127.0.0.1/STATIC/IMAGES/MY.JPG. (I put blank space between http and rest of url so links don't get generated).

Comment: Also, I have told you to use $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], because it will always show to your root folder. And use relative path like '/static/images/my.jpg' for html, because your browser understand what is root url (you don't have to specify it).
Since I've spent quite time answering various questions of yours, IF this answer helped you, please mark it as ANSWER! For any other question, please open another thread or PM me. Thank you!

Comment: 1) I meant to type $html_url = "//STATIC/"; that's been fixed above. No change to the functioning of the code.
2) The HOSTS file is configured properly.
3) $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] returns c:/xampp/htdocs/MAIN
4) I'm trying to access STATIC within code in the MAIN url.
5) Your solution does not work when the images are referenced in the HTML aspects of the code, vs the PHP functions, see my UPDATE 3 again. HTML that attempts to display "C:/XAMPP/HTDOCS/MAIN/../STATIC/IMAGES/MY.JPG" fails; on the other hand, that same string passed to getimagesize() works. Why would that be the case?

Comment: I appreciate that you're trying to help me with this, but I can't upvote your answer because it doesn't work...

Comment: Never mind the upvotes! I've been looking at this for one hour now and need to go to sleep. Your root is "C:\xampp\htdocs\", and $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] returns you "C:\xampp\htdocs\main" because index.php is in MAIN folder. Which explains why browser is able to load "//STATIC/images/my.jpg" (double slash is useless). you need to let $html_url = "/STATIC/";, but you could set php_url like this 
$php_url = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/../STATIC/";
I'm totally improvising, but that's only reasonable thing I can think of based on rereading everything 10 times in a row. :)

Comment: Again, I appreciate your attempt to solve this problem with the admittedly limited info I can provide here. I would PM you but I cannot see a way to do so from your profile. Again, the issue is that a URL with /../STATIC in it may be passed to PHP routines for processing, but when that URL is used in an HREF for displaying the data (in this case, a JPG), it does not display, nor is it clickable from the source to bring up the JPG image.

Comment: Again, there was a misunderstanding. I thought it was clear to you that URL and filepath cannot be the same. PHP reads from filepath, html/browser needs URL. I didn't realize you want to use the same variable for both. This will not be possible. The shortest way is what I said in last comment:  $php_url = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/../STATIC/IMAGES/my.jpg"; and $html_url = "/STATIC/images/my.jpg". This should work, because it is just an alternative to your UPDATE 3.Or you COULD put $filename = "/STATIC/IMAGES/my.jpg" and append that to your $php_url and $html_url.